# TxOutRefNotFound when using Plutus.Contract.Wallet (getUnspentOutput)

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, utxo

I am trying to get a UTxO of the current wallet, use it to mint a token via the `OneShotCurrency` type, but I keep getting the following Error:

`(TxOutRefNotFound (TxOutRef {txOutRefId = b2f06756e65c009ced73c87919e4f8dd0e640b002a247083354f7122f82d312f, txOutRefIdx = 10}))`

Here are my lookups and tx construction. Thanks for any help!

```
[...]
do
    ppkh   <- ownPaymentPubKeyHash
    oref   <- getUnspentOutput
    utxos  <- utxosAt (pubKeyHashAddress ppkh Nothing)
    let
        pol  = curPolicy $ OneShotCurrency { curRefTransactionOutput=(txOutRefId oref, txOutRefIdx oref), curAmounts=(PlutusTx.AssocMap.singleton myTokenName 1) }
        mVal = Value.singleton (scriptCurrencySymbol pol) myTokenName 1
        d    = [...]
        lookups       = Constraints.unspentOutputs utxos                            <>
                        Constraints.mintingPolicy pol                               <>
                        Constraints.typedValidatorLookups validatorInstance
        tx            = Constraints.mustSpendPubKeyOutput txOutRef                  <>
                        Constraints.mustPayToTheScript d (mVal <> Ada.adaValueOf (getAda 3000000))  <>
                        Constraints.mustMintValue mVal                              <>
                        Constraints.mustBeSignedBy ppkh
    ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraints validatorInstance tx
    awaitTxConfirmed $ getCardanoTxId ledgerTx
    logInfo @P.String "Initialized"
[...]
```

Comment: More context is needed. Did you run this contract using PAB (`plutus-pab`) or using `plutus-contract` emulator? When you're saying "current wallet", what are you referring to?

Comment: I ran it using the `plutus-contract` emulator.

Comment: The `txOutRef` variable is undefined. Is it actually `oref`?